# Android Communication Error after 2.3.4 update

Tags: android

My Droid X2 was just updated Android Version 2.3.4 and system version 1.3.380.MB870.  I'm using the phone for development and noticed that right after the update I started getting lot's of extra logcat activity.  One error that is constantly being printed is

```
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector: Communications error
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector:     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector:     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:238)
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector:     at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:98)
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector:     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector.java:99)
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector:     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.run(NativeDaemonConnector.java:83)
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector: Error in NativeDaemonConnector
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector:     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector:     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:238)
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector:     at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:98)
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector:     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector.java:99)
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector:     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.run(NativeDaemonConnector.java:83)
10-14 10:47:12.153  1476  1507 E TundConnector:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what this is indicating?  I've noticed that my location services don't seem to be working as well in my applications mapActivity as well.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the name **TundConnector** **should** imply that it's part of a package that uses Tund,a SSH tunneling daemon (basically, it connects a local socket to a socket on some random internet service via SSH).

Since it's trying & failing miserably to connect to a local socket I'd say that the tund daemons local socket has either been moved (by accident) or removed in the update you received.

What's the package name of the application that's spewing out the log?